# Formula for creating sequential auto-gen IDs in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm currently working on an inventory management project for my company and I want the spreadsheet to create a new, unique ID when new data is input.

I have it working to where it will import data from a Google Form, but I have having trouble with the ID gen.

```
=ArrayFormula(if(ISBLANK(B2:B), "", CONCATENATE("TMB",ROW(J6:J7))))
```

This is where I'm currently sitting at. I've tried multiple solutions and can't quite seem to figure it out myself. Ideally, I'd like to use an arrayformula or a Google apps script so that it will apply to the entire column.

The ID's should be the string "TMB" followed by a four digit number. It should also be expandable to account for future inventory, or even a different, more efficient system if you have a better idea (e.g. hex, alphanum, etc.) Thank you!!!

Comment: I'd guess that you need to do it with a script and probably PropertiesService.

Answer (score 0):

Not too difficult at all -- your idea about array formulas is interesting but if it's a product ID I think that it would be too easy to get that spreadsheet formula messed up and have all the IDs change in the sheet which would probably be bad.  Really ought to be a static value for product IDs

The easiest way that I have done something like this in the past is to go to the spreadsheet that you have receiving the form submissions and click on Tools -> Script Editor

Create the following functions:

```
function formsubmit(e) {
  var arrayvalues = e.values
  arrayvalues.unshift(productcode());

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  ss.appendRow(arrayvalues);
}

function productcode() {


var lastcode = parseInt(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('lastcode'));
var productcode = lastcode + 1;
PropertiesService.setProperty('lastcode',productcode)
return "TMB" + productcode
}

function setInitialCode() {
//Use this to set the starting integer value for the product Code

PropertiesService.setProperty('lastcode',ENTER YOUR STARTING INTEGER IN THIS PLACE)
}
```

Then in the script editor, go to `Edit -> Current Project's Triggers` and add a trigger and select the formsubmit() function and select the 'on form submission' trigger.

This should at least get you really close to a solution that works with some minor tweaking.